# getting request variable in DAO

Tags: java, struts

I have a scenario where i am unable to access a variable that is present in action class in DAO.
Its a struts framework with EJB and really old code where JSP are written in java class file. 
So basically its a reverse side code that is display from jsp comes from JAVA and EJB class files as interface.
This particular variable in action class is obtained from request variable. I want to use this variable in the DAO class. 
So i can think only of 2 options. Set this in form and use the form in DAO and get the value. But it wouldnt work as the form is reinitialised in the method it is used.
2nd set them in session or request but its value is null in DAO.

How else can I get this done. I just want to access the variable from action class in DAO. Please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: Some code snippets might make it easier to understand what you are trying to say. It sounds to me like you need to modify the method signature to pass back the data you want to use in the DAO...

Comment: I cannot change the method signature though.

Comment: Is it possible to make an overloaded method in DAO for this particular use?

Comment: can you show me a sample pls?

Comment: See answer below  :)

Answer (score 1):

### Use An Overloaded Method

Say you have

```
public void save(String firstName, String secondName){
    JDBC.save(firstName, secondName);
}
```

But now you need a new parameter! So you create essentially the same method and do this

```
public void save(String firstName, String secondName, String userId){
    //this to keep backward compatibility
    if(userId == null){
        //whatever is in the older method, in this case just the simple save
        JDBC.save(firstName, secondName);
    } else {
        JDBC.save(firstName, secondName, userId);
    }
}

public void save(String firstName, String secondName){
    save(firstName, secondName, null);
}
```